# CMake: корректное подключение Vulkan, GLFW и GLm

Tags: cmake, glfw, vulkan, glm

Уверен, подобные вопросы задавались не один десяток раз, но все же. Имеется желание написать проект с использованием Vulkan, GLFW и GLM. Зависимости локально разместил рядом с проектом в папке external. Работаю в CLion под Windows и столкнулся с CMake'ом.

Структура проекта следующая:

[image: Структура проекта]

Написал следующий CMake файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)

include_directories(external/vulkan-1.2.198.1/Include)
include_directories(external/glfw-3.3.6/include)
include_directories(external/glm-0.9.9.8/glm)

link_directories(external/vulkan-1.2.198.1/Lib)

add_subdirectory(external/glm-0.9.9.8/glm)
add_subdirectory(external/glfw-3.3.6)

add_executable(test main.cpp game/game.cpp game/game.h engine/engine.cpp engine/engine.h)
```

Vulkan в системе установлен, из папки установки скопированы директории Lib и Include. GLM и GLFW внутри своих директорий содержат свои CMakeLists файлы. Как я понял, их нужно добавить через add_subdirectory.

Заголовочные файлы всех трех используемых библиотек видны, однако, при попытке сборки он не видит функции GLFW (ту же glfwInit, например: undefined reference to `glfwInit`). Понимаю, что видимо нужно как-то использовать target_link_libraries.

Вопрос в следующем: как наиболее корректно и правильно подключить все к проекту и написать получше CMake файл?

Comment: Ну а линковщику указать библиотеки за вас мы должны? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindVulkan.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> из папки установки скопированы директории Lib и Include

Желание накопировать к себе зависимости (и положить их в `git`, ага) уже является звоночком грядущих проблем.

Как правило, современные библиотеки таскают с собой запчасти для `cmake` (которые выглядят как файлы с расширением `.cmake`), которые можно вызвать уже из своего `cmake` при помощи `find_package`, и потом уже культурненько все подключить.

Если библиотека идет без таких файлов, можно написать для нее файлики (в которых описать правила для работы `find_package`) самостоятельно.

Тогда при пересносе ваших исходников на другую машину, `cmake` сам найдет зависимости и все корректно подцепит.

А для того, чтобы зависимости корректно установить на машину к себе, можно и нужно использовать пакетный менеджер:

- на Linux - менеджер своего дистрибутива (apt, pacman, zypper, dpkg, ...)
- на форточке

  - `vcpkg` (который тесно интегирован с cmake), если пользуетесь Visual Studio
  - или `msys2/pacman`, если пользуетесь тулчейном `GNU`